# Generate angular component html file with builder

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I'm writing an angular package (`_shared_angular`) that provides an angular component. The `.html` file of this component should be generated though because it will be based on other files.

I don't want the `.html` file to be checked in, and I want it to be generated with the default build system.

I have tried writing a builder for it, but I struggle to generate the file for the package itself... the generated file is always put in the actual root package (that includes my package).

This is what my `build.yaml` looks like:

```
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      _shared_angular|iconsBuilder:
        generate_for:
        - lib/$lib$

builders:
  _shared_angular|iconsBuilder:
    import: "package:_shared_angular/builders/icons_builder.dart"
    builder_factories: ["iconsBuilder"]
    build_extensions: {"lib/$lib$": ["package:_shared_angular/lib/components/icon/icon_component.html"]}
    build_to: cache
    auto_apply: dependents
    runs_before:
    - angular
```

and this is what my builder looks like:

```dart
import 'package:build/build.dart';
import 'package:glob/glob.dart';

Builder iconsBuilder(BuilderOptions options) => IconsBuilder();

class IconsBuilder implements Builder {
  @override
  final buildExtensions = const {
    r'lib/$lib$': ['package:_shared_angular/lib/components/icon/icon_component.html']
  };

  @override
  build(BuildStep buildStep) async {
    final templateContent = await _getTemplateContent(buildStep.findAssets(Glob('package:_shared_angular/lib/components/icon/src/*.svg'));
    await buildStep.writeAsString(
        AssetId('_shared_angular', 'lib/components/icon/icon_component.html'), templateContent);
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

---

**EDIT:** It worked when I replaced `buildExtensions` with this: `r'lib/$lib$': ['lib/components/icon/icon_component.html']` but I don't understand why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it didn't work as expected, was because `auto_apply` should be `none`, but inside the target, it should read: `enabled: true` like this:

```
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      _shared_angular|iconsBuilder:
        enabled: true
```